# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "meter baza"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

Imaginemos que alguien dice:

> ¡Mi madre siempre **mete baza** en las discusiones con mi hermano! A la que oye que le digo algo, ya está allí para intervenir y darle la razón.

En España entendemos *meter baza* como lo que indica el DRAE en la definición de [*baza*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5FWOD09):

> **meter baza**
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Intervenir en asuntos o conversaciones de otros. No le dejaron meter baza en el diálogo.

¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión?

*Baza* se define así en la misma entrada del DRAE:

> *Del it. bazza 'ganancia'.*
>   1. f. Conjunto de cartas que en ciertos juegos de naipes recoge quien gana la mano.
>   2. f. Cosa que permite obtener una ventaja o beneficio. *El esprint es su mejor baza para ganar la carrera.*

Hay muchos casos de expresiones que vienen del mundo del juego (*hacer un farol*, *un [órdago](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R9NsJTE)*), por lo que la primera sensación es que debería ser lo mismo aquí:

La primera acepción remite a contextos de juegos de naipes, en los que la *baza* es la ganancia que alguien consigue al terminar un lance del juego. Sin embargo, entiendo que cuando se juega uno *recoge* la baza, cuando la expresión es *meter*. Por tanto, lo descartaría como opción de origen.

En cuanto a la segunda acepción, no me parece que tenga mucho que ver con este contexto.

Se me agotan las ideas o lo mismo es que estoy pasando alguna por alto. ¿Alguien tiene una hipótesis con más fundamento?

Comment: Interesante. En el CORDE hay usos de la expresión "meter baza" desde la década de 1830 como muy pronto. Y de la palabra "baza" con el significado actual desde el siglo XVI al menos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En 1726, el diccionario de Autoridades recogía la voz *baza* como "principio y fundamento", y ponía como ejemplo:

> Esta fué la primera *baza* de mis desengaños, y el principio de conocer que se ha de fiar nadie de palabras lisongéras.

En base a este significado, parecido a "razón" o "motivo", existía la siguiente expresión, que el diccionario actual no recoge:

> No dexar hacer *baza*. Metaphoricamente vale lo mismo que hablar mucho, y de modo que no dexa hablar à otro, ni decir su razón.

Una vez encontrada esta expresión, se entiende que alguien no deja hacer *baza* cuando le impide a uno *meterse* en su conversación, siendo precisamente eso, *meter* en la conversación su razón, lo que uno pretende cuando estás *metiendo baza*.

De hecho, en la siguiente versión del diccionario, de 1770 (la revisón del de Autoridades), la expresión ya venía recogida como:

> No dexar meter baza. Frase metafórica y familiar que significa hablar mucho alguno de modo que no dexe hablar á otro.

Curiosamente, en esta edición la acepción de *baza* comentada anteriormente ha desaparecido ya, quedando únicamente la relativa a los naipes.